# nestjs isn't injecting the typeorm connection in a custom validator

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

I am in the process of working out a custom validator to be used to verify if a value exists in the database

I managed to get the code to work by using `getConnection()` from the typeorm package. But I would ideally want to inject the typeorm connection object `constructor(private connection: Connection) {}` this gives me more flexibility with the testing.

```
import { BadRequestException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
} from 'class-validator';

import { Connection, getConnection } from 'typeorm';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'ExistsRule', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class ExistsRule implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {}

  async validate(value: number | string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    const { constraints } = args;
    if (constraints.length === 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Failed validating ${value} exists.`);
    }

    const str = constraints[0].split(':');
    const tableName = str[0];
    const columnName = str[1];

    const result = await getConnection().query(
      `select count(*) from ${tableName} where ${columnName}=$1`,
      [value],
    );

    // The record already exists. Failing the validation.
    if (result[0].count > 0) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    const { property, value } = args;

    return `${property} ${value} is already taken.`;
  }
}
```

DTO that is using this validator. (For completeness)

```
import {
  IsEmail,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsPhoneNumber,
  IsString,
  Validate,
} from 'class-validator';
import { ExistsRule } from 'src/customer/exists.validator';

export class CreateCustomerDto {
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  @IsEmail()
  @Validate(ExistsRule, ['customer:email'])
  email: string;

  @IsPhoneNumber()
  mobileNumber: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Customer]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret-to-be-put-in-the-env',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '300s' },
    }),
    CommonModule,
  ],
  controllers: [BookingsController, AuthController],
  providers: [CustomerService, AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UniqueRule } from './unique.validator';

@Module({
  providers: [UniqueRule],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is the custom validator class added to the module's `providers` array?

Comment: Nope, didn't get any errors @JayMcDoniel switcing over to getConnection from typeorm package helped me to get it working for now. But feels like has something to do with when the classes are bound into the IOC container.

Comment: Is the validator in the `providers` array of the same module using the validation? Do you have the class-validator container set to work with Nest?

Comment: I have the validator in a separate module (common) and it's in the provider array for the common module. And in the customer's module which I am using this validator, I have added it as an import

Comment: Okay, is the provider exported and is the class-validator container set up to work with Nest?

Comment: From the common module? No. class-validator seems to be working fine.

Comment: Do you know what I mean when I ask if the class-validator container is set up to work with Nest?

Comment: I don't think I do :(

Comment: [This issue shows how to set the proper container for class-validator and using a a custom validator with dependency injection](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/528#issuecomment-395338798)

Comment: Thanks for the direction @JayMcDoniel I hand't really understood the class-validator container setup until you shared that link. The solution for this problem was to configure class-validators container to use nestjs container.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JayMcDoniel's comments, and guidence. The solution was to edit main.ts and add the `useContainer` from `class-validator` module to instruct it to use the nestjs container.

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { useContainer } from 'class-validator';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CommonModule } from './common/common.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
  useContainer(app.select(CommonModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: A better solution in case validators are spread across modules would be `useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });`